# How to remove ıtem on localStorage?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage

I want to removeItem on localstorage but ı dont use localstorage.removeItem().Because ı want to delete a index in array(Sepet=array)
How can ı do it ?
thx

[image: Sepet Array]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70375187/edit) by copying the relevant code and paste it.

Comment: removeFromCart(product){
      let newCart=this.cart[0];
      let index=newCart.indexOf(product);
      newCart.splice(index,1);
      
      

      
    
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get object from localStorage you need the Helper: `localStorage.getItem('objectName');`. You will get a string and not a object. To transform this string to a Object you need the function `JSON.parse(string)`. And on this point you can work with the object. If you will delete item by index then remove it with `object[index]`and if you will remove item by value key like `id: 2` then use JS Object function function like `splice`to remove this item.

After that you have to stringify the object again to a string with `JSON.stringify(object)`. This string you can store in the lcoalStorage withe the methode: `localStorage.set(string)`

That is the entire workflow.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var array = [
{
'id': 1,
'name':'test1'
},
{
'id': 2,
'name':'test2'
},
{
'id': 3,
'name':'test3'
}
];

console.log(array);
localStorage.setItem('test', JSON.stringify(array));
var selected = 1;
 var getArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('test'))
getArray.splice(selected,1);
localStorage.setItem('test', JSON.stringify(getArray));
console.log(getArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

localStorage is meant to store String values, so if you want to remove an item at a particular index, bear in mind that you need to convert the stringyfied array into plain JS array, then remove the item with `array.slice()`, and save the updated array back to localStorage.

You can checkh the [Array.slice() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Comment: removeFromCart(product){
      let newCart=this.cart[0];
      let index=newCart.indexOf(product);
      newCart.splice(index,1);
     } ı did it this way but if ı am refresh to page, data is comeback.